# C#: Good way of finding the next and previous sibling control

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

What is a good way of finding the next and previous siblings of a control?

So for example if you have a panel with a number of buttons, textboxes, etc in it. Somewhere among those you have a user control which consists of a textbox and a button. When the button is clicked you for example want to find the name of the control that comes after this user control.

My goal is to create a user control that can swap its position with whatever comes before or after it (if there are any of course).

*I know this should be kind of trivial, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around this one...=/*

Comment: How do you define "next" and "previous"? Tab order? Order in which they are added to the container? Location based?

Comment: The order they are in the Controls collection of its parent. Visually, in this case, it is the control coming before or after it in a flow panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is rather specific for the `FlowLayoutPanel` case. Since it lays out the controls in the order that they appear in the controls collection, the trick is of course to find out the indices of the controls that should swap locations, and switch them:

```
private enum Direction
{
    Next,
    Previous
}

private void SwapLocations(Control current, Direction direction)
{
    if (current == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("current");
    }
    // get the parent
    Control parent = current.Parent;
    // forward or backward?
    bool forward = direction == Direction.Next;
    // get the next control in the given direction
    Control next = parent.GetNextControl(current, forward);
    if (next == null)
    {
        // we get here, at the "end" in the given direction; we want to
        // go to the other "end"
        next = current;
        while (parent.GetNextControl(next, !forward) != null)
        {
            next = parent.GetNextControl(next, !forward);
        }
    }
    // get the indices for the current and next controls
    int nextIndex = parent.Controls.IndexOf(next);
    int currentIndex = parent.Controls.IndexOf(current);

    // swap the indices
    parent.Controls.SetChildIndex(current, nextIndex);
    parent.Controls.SetChildIndex(next, currentIndex);
}
```

Usage example:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SwapLocations(sender as Control, Direction.Next);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can call Controls.GetChildIndex(control) with your current control to get its index, then just index into the Controls collection to get the previous and next siblings.

Comment: Could you provide an example? Preferably taking into account that it may or may not be the first or last control?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.GetNextControl(Control,bool forward);
```

Retrieves the next control forward or back in the tab order of child controls.

EDIT:

Use Controls collection and its methods.

Comment: Doh... how did I miss that one... But, does tab order stay the same when you reorder controls in a Controls collection? Or does it change accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

***For getting next control of the parrent:***

Panel.GetNextControl(currentControl, true);

***For getting previous control of the parrent:***

Panel.GetNextControl(currentControl, false);

Answer (score -2):

```
this.Controls.SetChildIndex(panelContainerOfHeaderAndUserControl1, 0);
this.Controls.SetChildIndex(panelContainerOfHeaderAndUserControl, 1);
```

That worked for me.
I've got two panels created at runtime, but the one with fill style and other top.
The panel with the fill style is overlapped by the top one.

Setting the Sibling order of the controls fixes that.